# Cordova build android - error: android sdk not found (but is installed and ANDROID_HOME set correctly on OS X)

Tags: android, cordova

On a fresh system I installed:

- Android Studio (current version downloaded from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)
- Oracle JDK 1.8.0_121

I then ran Android Studio and installed the default SDK, plus SDKs for versions 23, 22, 14, 11 and 8 (a selection of targets I've used for previous projects).  I downloaded platform tools 25.0.4 and SDK tools 26.0.1.

Then installed:

- NodeJS
- Phonegap

I set up my environment:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I pulled my existing Cordova project from a local git repo and ran:

```
phonegap platform add android@5.1.1
```

(because I have the plugin from https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin which has an issue that causes it to fail to build with the current version of the android platform spec; this command is suggested as a workaround)

```
phonegap build android
```

This gave the error:

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android ' ...
Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

Any suggestions what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of the SDK tools has removed support for a number of functions that the Cordova tools have been relying on, so no longer function correctly.  In order to use the latest Android SDK, you need to use version 6.2.0 of the Android platform module.  This hasn't been officially released yet, but is up on the NPM repository so can be used like this:

```
cordova platform add android@6.2.0
```

This clearly doesn't work with the `phonegap-facebook-plugin` module. Fortunately, there's a fork available that does work with this latest version:

```
cordova plugin rm phonegap-facebook-plugin
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID=appid --variable APP_NAME="app name here"
```

I also had to hunt down references to phonegap-facebook-plugin in my config.xml file, because it kept coming back otherwise.